# Black and White Print - Darkroom

Tags: darkroom

I am a novice, so I would greatly appreciate any insight.  My prints are fine, but the next day they turn pinkish.  I thought I wasn't washing enough, so I extended the wash time. And now they are turning blueish-gray.

My chemicals are fresh.  Developer 2 mins; Stop 30sec; and fix 2 mins. Any insight would be awesome

Comment: What developer/fix are you using? Which paper? What part of the print is turning blue/gray/pinkish (the image portion or the whole thing)? Sounds like a fixer problem to me (or perhaps a paper problem- exposed to light or old)... Try fixing a print for 4 or more minutes and see if the same thing happens...

Comment: Both developer and fixer are Kodak and Ilford paper

Answer (score 2):

It's the fix, quadruple time in fix.  Additionally, test the fix by cutting off a snippet of film, a piece of the tongue will do. Immerse this snippet in the fix, lights on. Watch it change from opaque to clear. If it clears, the fix is OK. Fix time is double time to clear. Wash developed and fixed prints 15 minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much!  You are correct, increased the fixed time, and it fixed it (no pun intended)  - thank you again!